# How to make Access query to search for multiple keywords in random order

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to make a database in which co-workers can save hyperlinks to instructional manuals which they upload.
When they save (via a form) a link to particular manual, they can also save some "keywords", in order to easily search for that particular manual later.
Just starting up, so feel free to point out an easier/better solution.
When people save keywords they just enter them into a form with 3 textboxes (keyword1, keyword2, keyword3) - sometimes all 3 get filled, sometimes only a couple.

Example table that contains the "keywords" and name of the person uploading the link:

```
ID  Name     keyword1   keyword2   keyword3  hyperlink
1   Peter    wrench     hammer     saw       www.test.com
2   Joe      axe        saw        hammer    www.test2.com
3   John     hammer     pipe                 www.test3.com
```

In the search form I have txtSrch1, txtSrch2, txtSrch3, where search criteria can be entered (this could also be a single textbox with commaseparated values, but don't know to do that).

When people search with data entered in one or more of the searchboxes the return should be the records where all search-words match the keywords in the tables - the order is irrelevant, so value from txtSrch1 could match value in keyword3 for example.

Expected result examples:
User entering saw and hammer in txtSrch1 and txtSrch2 should return

```
ID  Name     keyword1   keyword2   keyword3  hyperlink
1   Peter    wrench     hammer     saw       www.test.com
2   Joe      axe        saw        hammer    www.test2.com
```

User entering hammer, saw & axe in txtSrch1-3 should return

```
ID  Name     keyword1   keyword2   keyword3  hyperlink
2   Joe      axe        saw        hammer    www.test2.com
```

The output to be used on the result form is just the "hyperlink" string, so if I could only get this to be output from vba I can work on with that. I have tried constructing queries in Access to present it, but the "random" order of the keywords are challenging me.

All ideas highly appreciated -also ideas on changing the database construct all together.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to build up the SQL depending on whether the user has entered anything into each text box. Something like:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim strSQL As String
    If Len(Me!txtSearch1) > 0 Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " AND ((keyword1 LIKE '*" & Me!txtSearch1 & "*') OR (keyword2 LIKE '*" & Me!txtSearch1 & "*') OR (keyword3 LIKE '*" & Me!txtSearch1 & "*')) "
    End If
    If Len(Me!txtSearch2) > 0 Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " AND ((keyword1 LIKE '*" & Me!txtSearch2 & "*') OR (keyword2 LIKE '*" & Me!txtSearch2 & "*') OR (keyword3 LIKE '*" & Me!txtSearch2 & "*')) "
    End If
    If Len(Me!txtSearch3) > 0 Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " AND ((keyword1 LIKE '*" & Me!txtSearch3 & "*') OR (keyword2 LIKE '*" & Me!txtSearch3 & "*') OR (keyword3 LIKE '*" & Me!txtSearch3 & "*')) "
    End If
    If Left(strSQL, 4) = " AND" Then strSQL = Mid(strSQL, 5)
    If Len(strSQL) > 0 Then
        strSQL = "SELECT hyperlink " _
            & " FROM tblKeyword " _
            & " WHERE " & strSQL _
            & " ORDER BY Hyperlink ASC;"
        Me!lstSearch.RowSource = strSQL
    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "frmKeyword!cmdSearch_Click", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

In this example, I'm using the SQL to populate a list box.

Alternatively, if you wanted to use just one text box, with keywords separated by commas, then you can use a similar piece of code, but use `Split` to put the values into an array and then loop the array to build the SQL string:

```
Private Sub cmdAllSearch_Click()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim aData() As String
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    aData = Split(Me!txtAllSearch, ",")
    For lngLoop1 = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData)
        strSQL = strSQL & " AND ((keyword1 LIKE '*" & Trim(aData(lngLoop1)) & "*') OR (keyword2 LIKE '*" & Trim(aData(lngLoop1)) & "*') OR (keyword3 LIKE '*" & Trim(aData(lngLoop1)) & "*')) "
    Next lngLoop1
    If Left(strSQL, 4) = " AND" Then strSQL = Mid(strSQL, 5)
    If Len(strSQL) > 0 Then
        strSQL = "SELECT hyperlink " _
            & " FROM tblKeyword " _
            & " WHERE " & strSQL _
            & " ORDER BY Hyperlink ASC;"
        Me!lstSearch.RowSource = strSQL
    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "frmKeyword!cmdAllSearch_Click", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,